# Sharepoint - ADAL OAuth - file does not exist

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, adal

I am creating demo app that consumes sharepoint REST API. I'm able to successfully retrieve Bearer token (by client ID and certificate). App is registered in Azure AD and all Sharepoint permissions there are checked. I am able to retrieve all lists for example, but I am not able to retrieve a file. The same query works in browser. I assume it is permission problem. Do I have to register this app in SP? `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/IT/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` I tried it without success, but I think permissions in Azure AD should be sufficient. My GET query returns

```
{"error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The file /IT/vystupnidokumentydoc/filename.docx does not exist."}}}
```

Same query is OK in browser in user context.

REST call:

```
    private async static Task DoStuffInOffice365(string token)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application / json; odata = verbose");
        string url;

        url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/IT/vystupnidokumentydoc/filename.docx')";
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                Console.WriteLine("Fail!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("OK.");                
        }
    }
```

Get token:

```
private async static Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    //authentication context
    string authority = "https://login.windows.net/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/";
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

    var certPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    certPath = certPath.Substring(0, certPath.LastIndexOf('\\')) + $"\\{CERT_FILE}";
    var certfile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(certPath);
    var certificateBytes = new byte[certfile.Length];
    certfile.Read(certificateBytes, 0, (int)certfile.Length);
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(
        certificateBytes,
        PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD,
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
        X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
    ClientAssertionCertificate cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(CLIENT_ID, cert);

    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(P_URL, cac);
    return token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems the file was not found on the location provided. Please ensure the file exits on the site.

> Do I have to register this app in SP?

If you were developing SharePoint add-in, yes. And you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142384.aspx) for the authentication/authorization for the SharePoint add-in.

If you were not developing an SharePoint add-ins, we also can use the [Microsoft Graph-GetItem](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_list_children) to get the item and download the drive item through [this REST](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent).

Comment: File really exists. I am able to retrieve it with the same URL fom browser (user context). I can access lists and other REST operations from my app. Only files are problematic.